# Do new versions of OWA have an equivalent to the About page of OWA in Exchange 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-web-app, exchange-2016

Using the Exchange 2010 version of Outlook Web App (OWA) you could click the (?) button and then click About to get a really useful page containing information about the Mailbox server, Proxy server, Client Access server, etc.

Is there an equivalent with the 2016/2019 version of Outlook on the web?

The page is really helpful when doing migrations from Exchange 2010 to a newer version since you can see if the OWA is being proxied as well as where the mailbox resides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent with the 2016/2019 version of Outlook on the web?

Yep. Normally, we couldn't see the feature `About` from OWA 2016/2019. To realize it, you could switch your OWA version to the light one:

[image]

After you sign out/in your account again, you could refer to the following snapshot to view the information of your server:[image]

If you want to go back to the original version of OWA, you could uncheck the `Use the light version` button and sign out/in to make the changes work:[image]

Comment: A little sad that this is buried in the Light version but good to know it does exist! Thanks